# Appendix and List of Scientific Contribution page in "TOC"

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tableofcontents

I am having two troubles in formatting my `toc` of my thesis especially the `APPENDIX` and `List of Scientific Contribution`.

I am using `Easy Thesis Template` where it uses `Thesis class` based on `Book`.

The order of titles that I want in `toc` is as below:

```
ABSTRACT
LIST OF FIGURES
LIST OF TABLES
LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS
LIST OF SYMBOLS
CHAPTER 1
CHAPTER 2
CHAPTER 3
.
.
CHAPTER CONCLUSION
RFERENCES
Appendix A: Prepin File
Appendix B: GLYCAM
LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION
```

The problem that I am having are:

Problem 1): I want the entry `Appendix A` to be `APPENDIX A`

I have tried to use `usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}` and `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}` together with

```
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{A: Prepin File}
    \Blindtext[4][25]   %5 paragraphs, each 3 pangrams
\end{appendices}
```

but I did not get the `Appendix` to be as `APPENDIX` in the `toc`

Problem 2): I have added a new entry called `LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION` after the Appendix (My university require that).

But at the header of that page I get `A:    Prepin File` which supposed not.

I have tried to insert `\mainmatter` after the appendix section, but I get page numbering start from 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Here I show the Thesis.tex file contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, doublespacing]{Thesis}   % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\input{Settings/Packages.tex}
\input{Settings/Administrative.tex}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter      % Begin Roman style (i, ii, iii, iv...) page numbering

\widowpenalty=500
\clubpenalty=500


%% All the pages before the chapters ------------------------------
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/Title}
%%\newpage
%\input{Frontpages/DeclarationPage.tex}
%\input{Frontpages/Abstract}
%\input{Frontpages/Abstrak}
%\input{Frontpages/Acknowledgements.tex}
%%\newpage
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/TableOfContents.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/ListOfFigures.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Fixed/ListOfTables.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Abbrev.tex}
\input{Frontpages/Symbols.tex}
%##################################################


%% The Body -------------------------------------------------------
\setstretch{1.3}  % Return the line spacing back to 1.3 the whole document.
\mainmatter       % Begin normal, numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy}  % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style

\newpage
%\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter2}
\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter4}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter5}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter6}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter7}


%% Reference---------------------------------------------------
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}
\backmatter % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Bibliography

\begingroup
\begin{normalsize}
\bibliographystyle{Files/vjHarvard3}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \setlength{\bibsep}{10pt}
    \setstretch{1}
\bibliography{Backmatters/References/all_thesis_chapters}  % The references (bibliography) 
\end{normalsize}
\endgroup



% FOR APPENDIX
\include{Backmatters/testAppendix}
\include{Backmatters/testAppendix2}


% List of publication
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}}
\input{Backmatters/listofpublication}


\end{document}  % The End
```

I wish to get some help to solve the Appendix and the additional page `List of Scientific Contribution`. Many thanks in advance.